# how to check 1 is prime number in java and Hashmap's output is wrong for String type

Tags: java, string, hashmap, primes

I am currently solving [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-running-time-and-complexity/copy-from/22215214) on Hackerrank, and below is the code that I have written so far.

When I ran it, there are a couple of errors: the output is totally wrong even though the input and the process are correct, and when the input is 1, it does not add it into my hashmap. I believe that both errors exist because of using HashMap. For example, if the input is

3(testcases) ==> 12, 5, 7.  It will print out Prime, Prime, Not prime  instead of the correct output like Not prime, Prime, Prime.

For more information, I commented out the lines,saying "output purposes". You can see, it added to the hashmap in correct order, but when it prints, it messed up.

So, I am just curious if someone can please explain why printing is wrong, and fix for the part when the input is 1.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] myarray = new int[n]; // read number of testcases

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ // add input to my int array
        myarray[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }

    HashMap<Integer, String> newmap = new HashMap <>(); // create empty hashmap
    int temp;
    int value;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){   // loop based on num of testcases
        temp =myarray[i];
        boolean isprime = true; 
        if(temp ==1){   // hardcode for input 1
            isprime = false;
            continue;
        }
        for(int j=2;j<=temp/2;j++){     // checking whether the input is prime or not
            value = temp%j;
            if(value==0){
                isprime = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(isprime==true){  
            //System.out.println("temp(Prime): "+temp); //output purpose
            newmap.put(temp,"Prime");
        }
        else{
            //System.out.println("temp(Not prime): "+temp); //output purpose
            newmap.put(temp,"Not prime");
        }
    }

  Set set = newmap.entrySet();
  Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
  //printing out values of the each element in hashmap(newmap)
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
    }


   }
}
```

Comment: The `continue` statement in the `temp==1`case is unnecessary (and incorrect).

Comment: The `continue` in the `for (int j = 2...` part is also unnecessary and can be replaced by a `break` (it will keep checking other moduli after you've confirmed it isn't prime).  Better yet: instead of setting `isPrime = true` and processing later; add to your `Map` there, and `continue` your outer loop.  If you get past the inner `for` without ever having `put`, you can then add `"Prime"` to your map for that value of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HashMap doesn't have predictable order. However, you can print out the keys associated with each value like this:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = newmap.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    int key = iter.next();
    System.out.println(key + "=" + newmap.get(key));
}
```

This will output:

> ```
> 5=Prime
> 7=Prime
> 12=Not prime
> ```

**EDIT**: As suggested by [MeBigFatGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100565/mebigfatguy) and [smarx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94559/smarx), an entrySet() iterator is better while used with an enhanced loop.

**Example**:

```
for (Map.Entry mentry : newmap.entrySet())
{
    System.out.format("%s = %s\n", mentry.getKey(), mentry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: better still to use the entrySet() iterator to avoid map lookups in the loop, and also an enhanced loop would be easier and simpler to read.

Comment: I'd suggest `for (Map.Entry mentry : resultMap.entrySet()) { System.out.format("%s = %s\n", mentry.getKey(), mentry.getValue()); }`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I am just wondering if anyone could provide how to check prime number (to take care of input case ==1)?  I am trying to figure out, but I still have no idea how to figure out.

Comment: @harrisonthu There's nothing wrong with having the special check for 1. Keep in mind that you are also not checking for number less than 1. Another option is to not allow the input into the `myarray` if the numbers are less than 2. You can have an inner while loop that keeps checking until you put the number from sc.nextInt() in that array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that your myarray is not sorted and and when you are inserting into newmap , it's not getting inserted in the desired order.

I recommend you to sort the array and used ordered map like LinkedHashMap or linked list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] myarray = new int[n]; // read number of testcases

    Arrays.sort(myarray);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // add input to my int array
        myarray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    HashMap<Integer, String> newmap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(); // create
                                                                            // empty
                                                                            // hashmap
    int temp;
    int value;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // loop based on num of testcases
        temp = myarray[i];
        boolean isprime = true;
        if (temp == 1) { // hardcode for input 1
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 2; j <= temp / 2; j++) { // checking whether the input
                                                // is prime or not
            value = temp % j;
            if (value == 0) {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime == true) {
            // System.out.println("temp(Prime): "+temp); //output purpose
            newmap.put(temp, "Prime");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("temp(Not prime): "+temp); //output
            // purpose
            newmap.put(temp, "Not prime");
        }
    }

    Set set = newmap.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    // printing out values of the each element in hashmap(newmap)
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But, I believe that according to the problem description, if we sort the array, it will print out incorrectly.  To be specific, it mentions that read the integer and print Prime or Not prime  based on the integer that has been scanned.

Comment: Ok. I got you.Sorry for not getting your point earlier. Don't worry you may just use LinkedHashMap<>. It alone serves your purpose. :)

Answer (score 2):

@Jim Lewis and @Michael Markidis have already provided the right answers for how to fix the bugs in this code.

I think to satisfy the requirements of the coding exercise you're doing, you'll need to output the results in the same order as the input numbers, so you'll want to collect the results into something with an order, rather than the (unordered) `HashMap`. Here's some slightly cleaned up code that uses an `ArrayList` instead (though frankly you should be able to just print out the results as you go):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] inputs = new int[n]; // read number of testcases

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // add input to my int array
            inputs[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int number : inputs) {
            boolean isprime = true;

            if (number == 1) { // hardcode for input 1
                isprime = false;
            } else {
                for (int j = 2; j <= number / 2; j++) { // checking whether the input is prime or not
                    if (number % j == 0) {
                        isprime = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            results.add(isprime ? "Prime" : "Not prime");
        }

        for (String result : results) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also do `results.add(number + " = Prime");` and `results.add(number + " = Not prime");` respectively.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the expected output.

Comment: @smarx, guess what, I solved the problem by using Arraylist datastructure, and the way you implemented is almost the same as I did.  :)  Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the Iterator over the entrySet of your Hashmap will return the entries in the same order you added them.  A plain old HashMap guarantees nothing of the sort (no pun intended).  Try using a LinkedHashMap instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Yes, I DID assumed that everything I add into my HashMap will print out the same order :)

Answer (score 1):

While checking for 1 , update in map before continue; 
Inside Inner for loop , 
Use break instead of continue

Some tweaks
 - If your array doesn't have duplicates then dont waste memory in
   hashmaps. Loop on array.

- coding exercises has large input to be read , use bufferedreader instead for faster throughput

  - use generics properly

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not understand the difference between continue vs break.  But, now I realized that I should have used "break" to leave the loop.